# File not found error. Cannot get the correct path

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I try to open up a file to create a pandas dataframe with the following command:

```
foot_ds=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/xatzo/LocalDisk/Data/S1-speed 3 km_h-trialno 1 - Right Leg - shoe.xlsx")
```

but i get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/xatzo/LocalDisk/Data/S1-speed 3 km_h-trialno 1 - Right Leg - shoe.xlsx'
```

i have tried all three ways 
with r"C:..."
with "C:\....."
and with "C:/....."

but i cannot get it to work.
Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is you dont change directory
Use os.chdir(path)

Comment: They're using an absolute path here - `chdir` doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT, file was not xlsx, was csv